# Quadrature formula on triangle

Tags: integration, polynomials, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am looking for a quadrature formula on the triangle, with points at the vertices and at the mid-edges, so 6 points, and that is exact for polynomials of degree at least 2, with weights strictly positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a simplex with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$.
Denote vertices with indices $1-3$ and midpoints with $4-6$.
Let $\ell_1(\xi, \eta),\,\ldots,\, \ell_6(\xi, \eta)$ be the Lagrange interpolation basis for the points. Then weights for the quadrature can be computed from
$$
w_i = \int_{T} \ell_i(\xi, \eta) d\xi d\eta
$$
Due to symmetry $w_1 = w_2 = w_3, w_4 = w_5 = w_6$, so we can integrate only $\ell_1(\xi, \eta) = \xi(2\xi - 1)$ and $\ell_4 = 4\xi\eta$
Then
$$
w_1 = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1 - \eta} \xi (2\xi - 1) d\xi d\eta = 0\\
w_2 = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1 - \eta} 4\xi \eta d\xi d\eta = \frac{1}{6}
$$
The requested quadrature does not require values at vertices, only at midpoints of the edges. It is exact for every polynomial in $x,y$ with the total degree not exceeding $2$.
$$
\int_{T} f(x, y) dxdy \approx \frac{\operatorname{area}(T)}{3}\left[
f\left(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)+
f\left(\frac{x_1 + x_3}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_3}{2}\right)+
f\left(\frac{x_2 + x_3}{2}, \frac{y_2+y_3}{2}\right)
\right]
$$

You can find more cubature formulae with references [here](http://nines.cs.kuleuven.be/ecf/). The one you're looking for can be also found in *A.H. Stroud, Approximate calculation of multiple integrals, Prentice-Hall, Englewood Cliffs, N.J., 1971.*

**Edit**. Every quadratic function in $x,y$ can be uniquely decomposed over Lagrange basis
$$
f(\xi, \eta) = \sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_{i} \ell_i(\xi, \eta)
$$
and since we request *exact* integration of every quadratic function
$$
\int_T f(\xi, \eta) d\xi d\eta = \sum_i \alpha_i \int_T \ell_i(\xi, \eta) d\xi d\eta \equiv \sum_i \alpha_i w_i.
$$
And since $\ell_i(\xi, \eta)$ is Lagrange basis, 
$$
\ell_i(\mathbf{r}_j) = \delta_{ij}
$$
and
$$
f(\mathbf{r}_j) = \sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_i \ell_i(\mathbf r_j) = 
\sum_{i=1}^6 \alpha_i \delta_{ij} = \alpha_j
$$
So we arrive to the only quadrature possible
$$
\int_T f(\xi, \eta) d\xi d\eta = \sum_i f(\mathbf r_i) w_i\\
w_i = \int_T \ell_i(\xi, \eta) d\xi d\eta.
$$

You can also approach the problem this way: suppose we've constucted some quadrature with positive weights. Let's apply it to $\xi(2\xi - 1)$. This function vanishes at every of six nodes except one vertex. At that vertex its value is $1$. But the integral of that function over the triangle is zero, so the weight also should be zero. Contradiction.

Comment: By using a proper linear transformation, any triangle $\triangle ABC\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ can be mapped to your simplex.  Hence, the required quadrature will be $\iint_{\triangle ABC}\,f(x,y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y \approx \frac{\Delta}{3}f\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)+\frac{\Delta}{3}f\left(\frac{C+A}{2}\right)+\frac{\Delta}{3}f\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$, where $\Delta$ is the area of $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Thanks, but my question states: "with weights for the vertices strictly non zero",  or I did not understand ?

Comment: @user253166 It is unique, so no luck with strictly positive weights

Comment: @uranix Ok, that is the answer I needed, thanks.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks, I forgot to map it back to the original triangle

Comment: @uranix Can you update your answer about the unicity of your  formula (and hence the non existence of the one I was looking for) so that I can accept your answer ?